# App freezes in background

Tags: ios, swift

When I put my app to background, wait for a couple of minutes and reactivate the app, the app and usually the whole phone freezes. When I pause the app in the debugger, I can see that the main thread is waiting for a semaphore:

```
Thread 1  Queue: com.apple.main-thread (serial)
    0 semaphore_wait_trap
    2 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow
    3 -[AAEventsManager addEvent:parameters:async:]
    4 -[AAEventsObserver onApplicationStateChanged:]
    5 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    23 UIApplicationMain
    24 main
    25 start
```

My applicationWillEnterForeground has no code and the app freezes before applicationDidBecomeActive gets called. If I add a background timer, which makes network connections, they run after applicationWillEnterForeground when the app and iPhone UI has frozen, but the connection always fails. Sometimes the app is restarted almost immediately when it comes to foreground as frozen. The apps' cpu usage is 0%, memory usage 25MB and energy impact Zero.

I've tested with several iPhone 6 devices, which have iOS 9.2.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Do you use some 3rd party code or library with the prefix "AA"?

Comment: I have tried to minimize the use of 3rd party code and a quick case sensitive search to the pods project shows no classes with the prefix "AA".

Comment: What about other threads?  Is there something waiting to dispatch to the main thread, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out that AAEventsManager belongs to AppAnalytics pods lib.It's a binary lib so that's why I didn't find the class name. Removed the lib and does not freeze anymore.

Comment: And you found the error by going back the commit hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some version control? GIT? If yes, jump back a few versions and see at which commit the error occurs the first time - that's the easiest way to find such strange errors.

The fastest approach to find the commit with the error is to apply the binary search algorithm. Let's assume you have 100 commits:

- first check if the error happens on commit 1
- if yes, you have found the code with the error, if not jump to the half (commit 50)
- if the error is present on this commit jump to commit 75, if not again to the half (commit 25)
- and so on... always half up or half down until you find the exact commit with the error.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GIT. Not sure how far back I can jump before the Swift syntax is not anymore compatible with the new Xcode.

Comment: Try it, it seems your best bet.